# What additional software should I install for a Macbook?

Tags: 11.10, installation, drivers, package-management, macbook

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I've installed 11.10 it on my 2006 Macbook. What else should I install to make it complete? I'm talking about drivers and the like. Is there a complete package I can download somewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**1 
    Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t) and execute the following commands -**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**2. Install ‘Ubuntu Restricted Extras’ – codecs/plugins**

You need to install the audio mp3 (MPEG Layer 3) decoders as it’s required for playing your mp3 songs), similarly you need to install Adobe flash player on Ubuntu 11.10 for playing flash content such as YouTube Videos (although they are trying to replace the flash dependencies with HTML 5). You can install all these proprietary plugins/codecs by installing the package called ‘ubuntu restricted extras’. Open a terminal and execute the command -

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Restricted library/packages for playing encrypted DVD’s

Although you’ve installed ‘ubuntu-restricted-extra’, you still won’t be able to play any proprietary DVD (which is usually encrypted with CSS(Content Scramble System) ). Therefore You also need to install libdvdcss2, a free software library for unscrambling/accessing those DVDs. Open terminal and execute the following commands (You may need to reboot) -

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

**3 install cheese – webcam software/driver for your webcam**

If you want to use your webcam for taking pictures or recording videos then you must need a webcam software. Cheese is the most popular webcam software, and it’s already there in Ubuntu Software Center, or install it from terminal -

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

**4. Install Chromium Web browser for faster browsing
chromium**

Chromium - Browsing with Speed

Firefox is the default web browser in Ubuntu 11.10, which is slow and very unstable (if you’ve multiple tabs and add-on’s installed). On the other hand Chromium is pretty fast and it’s popularity is increasing exponentially. So it’s a must have Application on Ubuntu (or any other OS). Chromium supports all the extensions/themes that you use on Chrome. it’s one of the most popular software in Ubuntu Software Center. So you can install it in a single click from Ubuntu Software Center, or just type the command in terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T ) :

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

You should install some codecs like FFmpeg for playing multimedia contents on web.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

If you want to use chrome then go here – I’ve already explained about – installing Google Chrome on Ubuntu 11.10, in detail.

**5. Install VLC Player**

VLC player is one of the most popular open source media player. It is commonly called as – ‘all in one‘ media player, it has lot of features that you expect from a modern media player. On Ubuntu 11.10 – it’s a must have application – for video player it’s probably the best one. VLC player is capable of playing a wide range media formats such as mp3, avi, mp4, flv etc. Since it’s available in Ubuntu Software Center – you can either install it from there or type the command -

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

**6. Install any Image editing program**

An image editing/creating software is necessary for every one, by default no such program is installed. So you’re recommended to install an image editor.

GIMP is the most popular open source and free image editor, having features similar to Adobe Photoshop. GIMP has a lot of powerful features which allows you to create complex graphics designs/images. it is more suitable for intermediate users – those having some experience in image editing. To install gimp – either search in Ubuntu Software Center or install it from terminal -

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

For some extra set of brushes, gradients and plugins etc execute :

```
sudo apt-get install gimp-data-extras
sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry
```

Comment: These aren't MacBook specific nor do they seem to address the OP's request for driver-esque MacBook compatibility tools.

Answer (score 2):

For my 2008 MB, I put this line in the Startup Applications to make it more manageable:

```
synclient FingerLow=10; synclient FingerHigh=20
```

[image]

Comment: By 2008 MB, do you mean MacBook? Or something else?(Megabyte comes to mind)

Comment: MB = MacBook; 2008 is the year

Comment: Aah. I wasn't sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "more manageable"?

Comment: @somehume If memory serves, I meant "more sensitive". Without this configuration, the MacBook touch pad required lots of pressure before it would respond.

Comment: That's good to know. I have a cart of old MacBooks that I may begin to use with Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should list the version of Ubuntu that you are using.

The first questions that you need to ask yourself are what is missing (at least according to your knowledge) and what do you want it to do? "Complete" could mean various things to different people.

Answering the question of whether or not you are missing a driver can be answered by checking the functionality of your hardware. For instance, are all drives, bluetooth, wifi and display properly functional? You can check your drives by inserting media to removable drives or browsing (after mounting) hard drives. For Bluetooth and wifi, check your connectivity. Verify that they properly transmit and receive data. As far as video, verify that your video is displayed properly; you can do this by eye or via the graphics card properties in the system.

Answer (score 0):

If things are missing you could run the test that comes with Ubuntu. It's called "system testing", look for it in the unity dash. Running this will allow you to identify any problems and then you can ask more direct questions on how to fix them, for example if DVDs won't play we could point you to this post: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-enable-dvd-playback-in-ubuntu-11-04/ (Which is for 11.04, but I think it still works). Also if you provide an email address the profile will get uploaded online so other people can see how well Ubuntu performs on your model of laptop. (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/ubuntu-friendly-what-it-is-and-how-you-can-help/)