# Play DVD from Movie Player

Tags: video, dvd

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10. When I insert a DVD (into my MacBook Pro), I have the choice to play it through Movie Player, and it plays fine. However, if I then close Movie Player, and reopen it, I get stuck.

Pressing play doesn't do anything. `Open...` from the movie menu just allows me to select files, not the disk. `Open location...` requires me to type in a place. `Go` has everything disabled.

So, without ejecting the disk and inserting it again, how am I supposed to play a DVD from movie player?

Comment: I've just discovered that from Nautilus I get a tiny box in a corner that allows me to 'Open Movie Player'. This helps but it doesn't count if I want to do it from within Movie Player

Comment: It might be that the best answer to your question would be to point a different player like vlc or smplayer

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the Ubuntu restricted extras (plugins/codecs)?  Instructions to do so can be found on [this posting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70937/what-additional-software-should-i-install-for-a-macbook), on point #2.  Just asking, because whenever I have issues like this, it's usually because something isn't installed quite right.

Also, I'm not sure if you're using Movie Player because you are partial to it, or because it's all you've got right now.  I've tried several movie players on Ubuntu, and IMHO the best is VLC.  See point #5 of the same posting for info on installing that.

Answer (score 0):

In VLC, choose Media -> Advanced Open files.
Then, browse the folder of DVD and then simply play DVD. It's amazing.